# $.deferred is not working in time

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, jsonp, deferred

I've got the problem that I am using $.deferred to get the data in the right time when my function is getting called. I used an example from a answer which I got before: [Execution Time overlapse while AJAX JSONP Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804893/execution-time-overlapse-while-ajax-jsonp-call)

Now, when I debug to my code my debugging points in my main function are called first although the deferred should get the data in meanwhile. After that the debugger in the $deferred.done starts I get my data. As far as good but the data isn't returned in the time I would need it.

Here is a programmaticly list of the steps:

1. Invoke component
2. Starting AJAX call (doesn't wait till it it's finished because of async JSONP)
3. Tries to read data. is undefined because the call isn't finished yet
4. Returns an empty string
5. Component is being rendered with empty data
6. AJAX call is finished, returns data to component function
7. Component returns data, but nothing happens because the data is already sent and the other components are already rendered

This is the example code which I used to try the deferred pattern:

```
function getReady() {
  var deferredReady = $.Deferred();
  $(document).ready(function() {
    deferredReady.resolve();
  });
  return deferredReady.promise();
}

var firstRequest = $.ajax({ url: 'http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/' }),
    secondRequest = $.ajax({ url: 'http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/' });

$.when( getReady(), firstRequest, secondRequest
).done( function( readyResponse, firstResponse, secondResponse ) {
  var insertDiv1 = $('<div></div>');
  insertDiv1.html($(firstResponse[0]).find('section').html());
  var insertDiv2 = $('<div></div>');
  insertDiv2.html($(secondResponse[0]).find('section').html());
  $('body').append(insertDiv1, '<hr/>', insertDiv2);
});
```

This is the code I used before but didn't work because of time/execution problems:

```
sap.designstudio.sdk.Component.subclass("component", function() {
var that = this;

this.processDataFromServer = function(){

    function getData(callback){
        $.ajax({
                url: path,
                dataType: 'jsonp',  
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(data){
                    callback(data);
                }
            });
    };
    getData(processData);    
    function processData(data){
        this.processDataFromServer(data);
    };
}
this.mainFunction = function(newValue){
  if(typeOf(newValue) == "undefined"{
    this.processDataFromServer();
  } else {
    return newValue;
  }
}
}
```

Now I used the deferred example to get the right time for my main function to receive the data and to be able to return it. But it fails. :(

Comment: I don't understand, what is the problem? Your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/aL5v12mp/.

Comment: Side note: The whole `getReady` function seems a little wasteful (overuse of deferreds). Why not just place the code in a DOM ready (as per normal) and just worry about the Ajax requests?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just simplify it using `load` (with a selector) into your two appended DIVs:

```
$(function () {
    var insertDiv1 = $('<div></div>');
    var insertDiv2 = $('<div></div>');
    $('body').append(insertDiv1, '<hr/>', insertDiv2);
    insertDiv1.load('http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/ section:first');
    insertDiv2.load('http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/ section:first');
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aL5v12mp/